# Microsoft visual studio 2017 hangs on every xamarin action

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2017

I recently installed visual studio 2017.
When i create Xamarin android project or click on xamarin settings, it hangs and when click anywhere it says "Microsoft Visual Studio is busy".

Xamaring version is: 4.3.784

How can i fix this?

Comment: In the visual studio 2017 help menu open manage visual studio performance.   Does it show anything causing performance issues?

Comment: @KenTucker No. there is nothing

Comment: if you look in the task manager do you see high cpu or disk access?  I noticed that I see fewer hangs with visual studio since I switched my computers hard drive to an ssd

Comment: @KenTucker, It's using 2% of CPU. I have ssd hard drive too

Comment: I have the same issue. The problem is VS doesn't know where android sdk is located because I haven't installed it with VS. But now I can't open settings to set it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue in Visual Studio 2015 Update 3, and the update to [Xamarin 4.3.0.789](https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/vs/xamarin.vs_4/xamarin.vs_4.3/#4.3.0.789) yesterday has fixed it. I would suspect that this also fixes your issue in Visual Studio 2017.

This seems to be the [bugfix](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=52695) that helped.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix it by manually setting registry keys for the android SDK and NDK directory. No additional installation or update is required if you already have the android SDK and NDK installed on your computer.

Here's a snippet of the log that I found at `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Logs\15.0\monodroid-2017-03-17__00-01-06.2812.log`.

```
MonoDroidLog: Information: 0: [I:sdk]:                  Looking for Android SDK..
MonoDroidLog: Information: 0: [I:sdk]:                    Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Xamarin\VisualStudio\15.0_a0933f78\Android\AndroidSdkDirectory not found.
MonoDroidLog: Information: 0: [I:sdk]:                    Key HKLM\SOFTWARE\Xamarin\VisualStudio\15.0_a0933f78\Android\AndroidSdkDirectory not found.
MonoDroidLog: Information: 0: [I:sdk]:                    Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Xamarin\MonoAndroid\PrivateAndroidSdkPath not found.
MonoDroidLog: Information: 0: [I:sdk]:                    Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Android SDK Tools\Path not found.
MonoDroidLog: Information: 0: [I:sdk]:                    Key HKLM\SOFTWARE\Android SDK Tools\Path not found.
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with Visual Studio 2015 months ago. The problem was fixed by updating the Android SDK tools to the current version. Another way was to install the Android SDK via the Visual Studio Installer and changing the SDK path within Visual Studio to the downloaded SDK via Installer.

Edit: I just read a similar problem with Android SDK and Visual Studio windows is known in Visual Studio 2017 and will be fixed, see https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/26234/visual-studio-not-responding-when-trying-to-config.html

Comment: I installed Android SDK from visual studio installer, but still no luck. Maybe i have to wait for the update

Answer (score 1):

For me it solved by deleting .vs folder in solution folder.