# Visual Studio 2017 does not working - Always freezing and saying "it's busy"

Tags: c#, wpf, xamarin, visual-studio-2017

Every time I trying to create some Xamarin project it freezees and when I try to click anyware in UI, pop ups a notification from Windows saying the the "VS 2017 it's busy" something like that. For task mananger still answers and runs normally. The same happens if go to Tools -> Options and try go to Xamrin category. I tried to explore other functions of the new IDE, same happens when I create a WPF project and try to access the toolbox with UI elements.
I created other kind of projects for test, and console projects and and the integration with Unity seems is working fine too.
I've tried repair the installation too but no success.

I tried to download the SDK and NDK through the VS Installer mentioned in other question but didn't fixed too. And what about the WPF toolbox, why is not working either?

[UI is freeze](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAAOM.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Microsoft visual studio 2017 hangs on every xamarin action](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42752864/microsoft-visual-studio-2017-hangs-on-every-xamarin-action)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try updating Visual studio 2017 from the installer,it worked for me. Thanks.